# jquery widget: get fresh view of DIV every time

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-widgets

here is a static div in my html page

```
<div id="target"></div>
```

I have make a custom dialog box using jquery widget. During initialization i do:

```
   _create:function(){
        ele =   $("#target");
        _this = this;
        this._attachEvent();
   },
    _destroy: function()
    {
        ele.modal('hide');
    }
```

here `modal` is bootstrap modal and here is a sample how i am adding a class dynamically

```
    _attachEvent:function(){
        this._on(this.element, {
            "click .delete": function(e) {
                ele.find(".clicks").addClass("deleting");
                $(e.target).html("deleting....");
            }
        }
```

and after that i am adding dynamic classes in the `#target` div and its child divs.

The problem is if I open the dialog second time, all previously added class remains there i.e. if i had added a class `X` first time, it will be remain there if i open dialog second time. and there so many runtime classes i am adding.

I want to get fresh view of `#target` every time I open dialog

Comment: can you share code of attachEvent

Comment: have you implemented a `_destroy` method ? (*is it called when closing ?*)

Comment: yah but how destroy will remove dynamically added classes. i am calling destroy but not doing anything inside that just closing dialog.